# for-loops in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

If I have the following code, what will the integer "i" be equal to after it executes? Does a loop increment after a break statement?

```
int i = 0;
for(int foo = 0; foo < 10; foo++,i++){
    break;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? http://ideone.com/

Comment: Why don't you execute it and print out `i`?

Comment: The `break` executes before the update part, so `i` doesn't change.

Comment: Homework question? Looks like it.

Comment: There was a time when you could still get a PM job without ever doing your own CS homework. Thankfully, those days are mostly gone. Enjoy your student loan debt!

Comment: I feel it is morally incorrect to answer this question . No such thing as a stupid question but surely a there is a thing called Lazy question.

Comment: I cannot but -1 this for not even pretending to give a crap.

Comment: I 100% looked this up out of laziness lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you put a println and see...

I'm going to say it ends up with what you started (i.e., zero -- the increment happens after the code in inside the for executes -- since you break out of it, it never gets to increment).

Comment: Your answer should be a comment.

Comment: Every time i ask a question here i re read it later and feel like an idiot. :P

Comment: Why do people keep upvoting Hunter? Originally I just had my snippy comment but I have actually answered it now.

Comment: Because it's obviously homework and 'answers' are discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info

Answer (score 5):

After a `for` loop finishes one iteration it executes the incrementor code (in your case `foo++,i++`). Since your loop breaks before it finishes one iteration neither `foo` nor `i` increments.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually look this up in the standard.  A for loop with a break, by definition, is like a while, goto, as so:

```
for( init; test; incr){
   break;
}
```

is

```
init
while(test){
   // do things
   goto end
   incr
}
end:
```

So, since the break is always executed, it never hts the increment part, and neither foo nor  i will be incremented.

Answer (score 0):

It prints `0`, which is exactly what you should expect it to print. The post increment clause is executed after the code block, but we are breaking in the middle of the code block. So the post increment is never executed.